# Yum dependency resolution choosing older version than requested

Tags: yum, rpm, dependencies

I have an RPM I am installing. Here's what `deplist` gives:

```
$ yum deplist path/to/my/rpm
....
dependency: jre*headless >= 1:1.8.0
 provider: java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless.i686 1:1.8.0.45-40.b14.fc20
 provider: java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless.i686 1:1.7.0.79-2.5.5.0.fc20
```

This is puzzling - why is `java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless.i686` being chosen?

```
$ repoquery --provides java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless.i686 | grep headless
    config(java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless) = 1:1.7.0.79-2.5.5.0.fc20
    java-1.7.0-headless = 1:1.7.0.79-2.5.5.0.fc20
    java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless = 1:1.7.0.79-2.5.5.0.fc20
    java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless(x86-32) = 1:1.7.0.79-2.5.5.0.fc20
    java-headless = 1:1.7.0
    java-openjdk-headless = 1:1.7.0.79-2.5.5.0.fc20
    jre-1.7.0-headless = 1:1.7.0.79-2.5.5.0.fc20
    jre-1.7.0-openjdk-headless = 1:1.7.0.79-2.5.5.0.fc20
    jre-headless = 1:1.7.0
    jre-openjdk-headless = 1:1.7.0.79-2.5.5.0.fc20
```

As far as I can see there's no provides for 1:1.8.0. I also tried:

```
$ rpmdev-vercmp 1:1.8.0 1:1.7.0.79-2.5.5.0.fc20
1:1.8.0 > 1:1.7.0.79-2.5.5.0.fc20
$ rpmdev-vercmp 1:1.8.0 1:1.7.0
1:1.8.0 > 1:1.7.0
```

So RPM version comparison seems to be working...

Why is yum chosing the older version of the JRE?

Comment: Fedora 20 is end of life. Please update to a current release.

Comment: Is that relevant to the question? Is it because the distro is EOL that the dependency resolution is incorrect? Surprising behaviour if so.

Comment: It means that there will never be another update, and that means F20 will never have a fix to the problem you have run into.

Comment: I don't understand how this is a problem with the contents of the repository. I have declared `jre*headless >= 1:1.8.0` and yet Java 1.7 is offered, even though `repoquery` doesn't list `>= 1:1.8.0` as a capability. It seems to me either `repoquery` doesn't list all capabilities, there's a bug in yum or I'm not specifying the requirement correctly. I'm betting on the last one!